# LEGO old discontinued model?

Tags: set-identification, creator

Does anyone know an old model from LEGO that was a 3 in 1 set featuring a black sports car, black truck and a drag racing car?

Answer (score 6):

You clearly are thinking of [Roaring Roadsters](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=4896-1).

[image: Main model]
[image: instructions]